# In R data tables, how to operate on a newly created variable in the same call?

Tags: r, data.table

Within `dplyr` I can create a single variable as a function of another, and immediately do something to that column by name.

e.g.

```
mutate(gearcarb = sum(gear, carb), 
       gearcarb_10 = 10* gearcarb)
```

But within `data.tables` this same approach yields an error.

```
mtcars_dt = data.table(mtcars)
mtcars_dt[, `:=`(gearcarb = sum(gear, carb), gearcarb_10 = 10*gearcarb)]
> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'gearcarb' not found
```

Can anyone help? I can't find anything in the documentation, although I'm sure as a relatively trivial issue there must be an easy answer.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` doesn't 'know' about the newly created column straight away, so you need to separate your expressions somehow

A couple of solutions, one is to chain the expression, the other is to do multiple operations inside `{}`

```
setDT(mtcars_dt)
mtcars_dt[, `:=`(gearcarb = `+`(gear, carb))][, gearcarb_10 := 10 * gearcarb]

## this one will return the last expression inside the {}
mtcars_dt[, gearcarb_10 := { gearcarb <- gear + carb; gearcarb_10 <- 10 * gearcarb }  ]
```

Comment: Thanks @SymbolixAU. What is the `{}` syntax commonly referred to? I would very much like to read up on this, looks powerful.

Comment: @JohnL_10 - in base R - take a look at `help("{")`. As for learning about `data.table`, their [FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html) is a great resource.